Suppress function lookup messages in Saxon
I am using Saxon 12.4 EE in a Java Swing application and want to know if it is possible to suppress the messages being displayed regarding looking for function definitions:

This is creating a large amount of messages that will be 'less than useful' to the end user of the application. I have looked in the Saxon documentation, but I am not seeing anything that I can easily identify as the way to suppress this information.

Have you unintentionally set -TJ for "tracing of the binding of calls to external Java methods" or a similar configuration http://saxon.sf.net/feature/trace-external-functions? Or do you get those messages without having set that option?

Was just reading through that area of the documentation again, and didn't think this applied. I was thinking this was related to 'extension' functions. But, after reading your comment, I went and looked at my config XML and do see that when it was created (by a previous team member) they did set the @traceExternalFunctions to 'true'. Will change that and report back on effects,

You're right that the behaviour doesn't match the documentation: all function searches are being logged. I'll look into this.

Based on the comment by Martin Honnen, I checked the config file for Saxon. Found that the @traceExternalFunctions attribute of <global> element was in fact set to true. Changed that to false and now get the desired results.
Thank you to Martin for helping me see it.
